# Bluemix not serving correct ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, https, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have just installed a wildcard ssl certificate on a custom domain, this is working fine for any subdomain of *.example.com. I can verify that the correct ssl certificate is being issued.

However the problem is with www. which is issuing the Bluemix certificate not my own certificate.

In the browser i am getting "Your connection is not private"

This server could not prove that it is www.example.com; its security certificate is from *.eu-gb.mybluemix.net. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

I am guessing that the problem is with Bluemix, how can i get Bluemix to serve up my certificate for www, baring in mind that it is serving up my certificate for other subdomains.

All help will be greatly recieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, the problem was with the DNS setup.

The key piece of information for me, was that my dns was point to 2 IP's of Bluemix 5.10.124.142, and 5.10.124.141, therefore only serving up my certificate on one, and the Bluemix default certificate on the other

From googling how to add a custom domain, i added a CNAME record to point to *****.eu-gb.mybluemix.net and an A record to 5.10.124.142

This is wrong, i need to change my CNAME record to be my actual domain now.

Comment: What is the link to the Bluemix documentation that says to change your CNAME?

Comment: @whitfiea Sorry, found information from googling and realised its not official documentation, please note i have changed my answer